# How to get the Title (or Label) of Activity with Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

Can we get the Title of an Activity with the Intent data?

When we put the label (title) of an activity in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.AlmacenesActivity_"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_almacenes" <-- this one
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

can we get that label/title ussing an Intent variable?

Comment: why you need the title using Intent? Is there a specific need?

Comment: i need to show the title of activity outside of activity. something like a dynamic menú where the activity label its shown for each item i add.

Comment: my object its like: object.setIntents(intent1, intent2, ... , intentN); so if i dont have to add manually each label better.

Comment: ok, so you can fetch the Current Activity's title using ActionBar API and then use like `intent.putSting("title", actionBar.getTitle().toString())`, and retrieve it in Another Activity using `getIntent`

Comment: I was looking for something direct like intent.getComponent.getLabel(); or any trick but i think there is not direct way.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
String classTitle = actionBar.getTitle().toString();
```

Comment: i mean, with an Intent, because i need to show the title of activity outside of activity.